# Parse xml file which has multiple child elements and sub root elements using java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am looking for a Java tool which can parse the XML file which has multiple child elements and sub root elements,
Here, is the sample content from my xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root_element>
   <MajorVersion>10</MajorVersion>
   <MinorVersion>0</MinorVersion>
   <sub_element1>
      <ActivateRule1>0</ActivateRule1>
      <ActivateRule12>false</ActivateRule12>
      <Classes>
         <Class>
            <Name>Default</Name>
            <Type>User</Type>
            <Data>data content</Data>
            <Description>User class</Description>
         </Class>
         <Class>
            <Name>class2</Name>
            <Type>User</Type>
            <Data>data conten2</Data>
            <Description />
         </Class>
      </Classes>
      <Policies>
         <policyDefinition>
            <Name>p1</Name>
            <Id>121</Id>
            <Type>Binary</Type>
            <Valued>false</Valued>
            <Description>Destination</Description>
            <AssociatedClass />
         </policyDefinition>
         <policyDefinition>
            <Name>p1</Name>
            <Id>121</Id>
            <Type>BinaryData</Type>
            <Valued>false</Valued>
            <Description>Destination</Description>
            <AssociatedClass />
         </policyDefinition>
      </Policies>
      <Filters>
         <f1>false</f1>
         <f2>true</f2>
      </Filters>
   </sub_element1>
   <sub_element2>
      <Policies>
         <policyDefinition>
            <Name>p1</Name>
            <Id>121</Id>
            <Type>BinaryData</Type>
            <Valued>false</Valued>
            <Description>Destination</Description>
            <AssociatedClass />
         </policyDefinition>
         <policyDefinition>
            <Name>p1</Name>
            <Id>121</Id>
            <Type>BinaryData</Type>
            <Valued>false</Valued>
            <Description>Destination</Description>
            <AssociatedClass />
         </policyDefinition>
      </Policies>
   </sub_element2>
</root_element>
```

Can anyone please suggest which java tool can be used, and I also read that xml parsers are also suggested based on the file sizes, My typical file sizes will be of 2 to 3Mb
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic for this site - see point 4 in the [Some questions are still off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) list. But for "inbuilt" XML handling in core Java, you can look at SAX, StAX, and the other tools presented in the [JAXP family](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html).

Comment: Hi andrewJames thanks for suggestion, Sorry I wasn't aware of the rules of the Q&A But in SAX, Stax I read it can be suitable for XMLS which has only one root element but where as my xml is having multiple set of elements

Comment: The XML in your question is not valid - it is missing a closing `</sub_element2>` tag at the end (before the final closing `</root_element>` tag). I assume that is just a copy/paste problem and is not the case in your actual XML.

Comment: Having said that, if you fix the missing tag, then you will have valid XML. I am not sure what you mean by "_my xml is having multiple set of elements_". XML generally _does_ have multiple sets of elements. But it must have only one _root element_ and your sample does indeed only have one root element. Can you clarify what you believe your issue is?

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes that is the copy paste issue fixed the xml, Regarding the issue I took sample example of SAX from the tutorial point but using that approach I am unable to get the exact data like,  When I grep qName for "Type" I am getting the values both from the Classes block and Policies block because the line "Type" exist in both", I was unable to add the condition that I need to get the type value from the classes block only (or) Simple to say how can I get the each blocks value separately.

Comment: It sounds as if you have reached a point where you can ask a new, much more specific question. You can do what you are asking about with SAX and StAX.  Another very different approach is to [use xPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html), which lets you access specific items in your XML. It all depends on what you want to do with the data you need to extract. I recommend asking a new question with specific code and a specific problem.